# Not sure how to decipher this method signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

What is the correct method signature for this method `handleError` method?

`tslint` is saying `expected call-signature: 'handleError' to have a typedef (typedef)`.

The code itself is:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

private handleError<T>(result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
    console.error(error);
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

I thought it was returning a type of `Observable<T>` but clearly that doesn't pass.  I then thought it might be a method that returns a type of `(error: any): Observable<T>` but again, that doesn't pass.

Comment: [`of` is a keyword in JavaScript/TypeScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)... that might be causing an issue

Comment: This is a function that returns a function. That returned inner function takes an error of type `any` and returns an `Observable<T>`

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's why I included the import for Observable, to show where that was coming from.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks.  I was missing the `=>` part.  It took me an inordinate length of time to see that

Comment: TIL [that you can name a variable `of`, and `for (let variable of array)` loops still work.](https://i.itsosticky.com/zilt4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

`private handleError<T>(result?: T): (error: any) => Observable<T> {`

I was mis-typing the `=>` as a `:` above.   Thanks guys